# Simultaneous multitasking in Django

Tags: python, django

I have in my web project a time consuming function. While the function is doing its computations, a web page should be rendered informing the user that the results will be sent by email once the computation is done.

If I put the rendering after the function call, the web page wont be rendered until after the time_consuming_function() had finished and that would make the response senseless.

```
views.py:

def web_function(request):
    ...
    time_consuming_function()
    return HttpResponse()
```

Is python threading the only way to go?

---

**Update**

Ended up using cellery, since it seemed better documented than ztaskd

Comment: Not really, I'd rather integrate celery into the project, set up a consumer server, so the tasks are sent there from django, django render's the page, and periodically updates the contents by ajax, where the information is retrieved again by django from the database, as celery's worker process is putting there the results.

Comment: Can you please enlighten me how you used celery, im rather new to celery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you look at a task-scheduling framework, such as Celery (or just plain [Rabbit MQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html))

Comment: Although it's the right idea, I wouldn't recommend that. DJ Celery is real PITA.

Answer (score 6):

The way to go is to use [ztaskd](https://github.com/dmgctrl/django-ztask) to execute `time_consuming_function()`.

```
from django_ztask.decorators import task

@task()
def time_consuming_function()
    ...
```

views.py:

```
def web_function(request):
    ...
    time_consuming_function.async()
    return HttpResponse()
```